# How to unclock Android screen when install from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm new in Android developing (I'm a developer iOS from 3 years) and the very first thing that I notice in Android is that when I install my app from Android I need to unlock the screen manually.

This might seem like an unimportant thing but very often I'm wait in front of the screen for a few seconds and then I realize that I have to unlock the device manually.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I don't know about auto unlock but you could set "Stay Awake" in developer settings on your phone. This means the screen will not lock when you are connected to your computer. Not compatible with all phones due to some screen types.

Comment: Autounlock = if I have the tablet in standby when I install from IDE the tablet automatically wake up and show me the first Activity of the app

Comment: @conor put your comment in an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know about auto unlock but you could set "Stay Awake" in developer settings on your phone. This means the screen will not lock when you are connected to your computer. Not compatible with all phones due to some screen types.

Also, you could have a scout around the Play Store. There are numerous attempts at this but with varying results I suspect.

--Conor